# Only seconds on x-axis Highstocks

Tags: time, axis, highcharts

I'm using highstocks for a project. I take the data from a JSON file :

```
[
[1,-2],
[2,-9],
[3,-5],
[4,-7],
[5,-5],
[6,0],
[7,-7],
[8,-6],
.....
]
```

The first column is the time, in seconds. But on the graph, I have something like that :
00:00:03

And I want: 3

I've searched in the Highstocks API, but there's a lot of date-format parameters, and I don't know which one to use.

Thank you !

Comment: Please provide links of your references in your question and also create a fiddle of your code !

Comment: You need to multiply your eac x by 1000, because in the javascript 3 means 3 miliseonds. 3s = 3000